# How to process a text file line by line in Ruby, and mark the already processed lines with a hashmark symbol?

Tags: ruby, text, queue, locking, line

I would like to write a simple download helper script in Ruby.

Download URLs take place in a text file, line by line.

My program should take them one by one, download the referenced file, and then mark the already processed line with some symbol, such as #.

Further problem is that the text file containing the URLs can grow while being processed, because sometimes I would like to add new URLs at the end of the text file, meanwhile it is being processed by the program.

I found this gem, called FileQueue: https://github.com/pezra/filequeue which do something similar: it takes out always the first line, and can push a line at the end of the file, however it removes the already processed lines, and that is a problem, because sometimes I need the URLs after they have been downloaded.

How can I achieve this in clever Ruby way, or maybe does Ruby have a built-in method for this?

Comment: Why not use a database like https://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3/versions/1.3.11?

Comment: What do you mean by, "...the text file containing the URLs can grow while being processed:..."? If you have control over when the two operations take place there's no problem, but if you are modifying the file in one thread and adding text to it in another, you obviously have a potential problem of collisions. Using a database, as suggested by @iGan, is the obvious answer in the second situation, as any reasonable database will allow you to employ transactions to avoid collisions. You do need to clarify the question (with an edit).

Comment: the text file containing the URLs can grow while being processed, because sometimes I would like to add new URLs at the end of the text file, meanwhile it is being processed by the program.

Comment: I would suggest using DB structure to store your urls since it is now dynamic data.

Comment: I just happened to see your last comment, which I assume was directed to me. For me to be notified of your comment by SO you need to include my username (prefaced with “@“) in the comment (but given your rep I expect you know that).

Comment: No, I didn't know that till now. :| One lives and learns.